# PFQuery not picking up variable

Tags: swift, parse-platform

A User enters text into a textField, and then I want a Parse Query to get some results based on that field. I am "KVC syntax challenged"!, so I am wondering what code I need to pick up the newText var in the Parse filter. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me...

```
 func wordEntered(alert: UIAlertAction!){
        // store the new word
        newText = newWordField.text! as String
        // query Parse
        getList()
    }

  func getList() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "WordList")
    query.whereKey("SharingCode", equalTo: "@\(newText)") // NOT PICKING UP newText??

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil {
                for object in objects! {
                 // process the objects
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dumb error. "\(newText)" works fine.